# Disabling touchpad when desktop starts

Tags: scripts, touchpad, xfce

I would like to turn my touchpad off when my desktop starts. How can I do that? I already found that the following script outputs 14:

```
xinput list | grep -Eo 'TouchPad\s*id\=[0-9]{1,2}' | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,2}'
```

But how can I configure my computer such that the script

```
xinput set-prop 14 "Device Enabled" 0
```

would be run when starting XFCE?

Comment: Are you using the synaptics driver? If yes, try `synclient Disabled=1`

Comment: I'm not using that driver. My question is that how to run the script automatically when desktop starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type:

```
xfce4-session-settings
```

Then open the tab "Application Autostart" and click on 'Add'.
Alternately you can create a .desktop file and put it in ~/.config/autostart.

A simple .desktop file could be:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=test
Comment=test
Exec=path_to_script_or_command
Icon=
Terminal=true
StartupNotify=false
Hidden=false
OnlyShowIn=XFCE;
```